# Showing WP Job Manager Custom Field into popup window

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using WP Job Manager plugin to allow submitting applications for work on my site. Followed [official documentation](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/resume-manager-editing-submission-fields/#section-1) by plugin developer I created custom phone fields with this function:

```
// Add field to admin
add_filter( 'resume_manager_resume_fields', 'wpjms_admin_resume_form_fields' 
);
function wpjms_admin_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['_candidate_color'] = array(
    'label'         => __( 'Phone', 'job_manager' ),
    'type'          => 'text',
    'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter your phone', 'job_manager' ),
    'description'   => '',
    'priority' => 1
);

return $fields;

}

// Add field to frontend
add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields', 'wpjms_frontend_resume_form_fields' 
);
function wpjms_frontend_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['resume_fields']['phone'] = array(
    'label' => __( 'Phone', 'job_manager' ),
    'type' => 'text',
    'required' => true,
    'placeholder' => '',
    'priority' => 1
);

return $fields;

}

// Add a line to the notifcation email with custom field
add_filter( 'apply_with_resume_email_message', 
'wpjms_color_field_email_message', 10, 2 );
function wpjms_color_field_email_message( $message, $resume_id ) {
$message[] = "\n" . "Phone: " . get_post_meta( $resume_id, '_phone', true );  
return $message;
}
```

and I tried to show into green Contact popup button for ex [here](https://www.asistesocial.es/resume/victoria-hlta9gy-auxiliar-de-enfermeria-vizcaya/), but it seems that it doesn't show nothing using this code that some developers suggest:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_phone', true ); ?>
```

I tried to show into Green popup place using the same code, but it didn't work.. Phone is inserted into admin area for that application, and it's shown when check. This is how looks that popup area:

```
<div class="resume_contact">

    <a href="#resume-dialog" class="small-dialog popup-with-zoom-anim button"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <?php esc_html_e( 'Contact', 'workscout' ); ?></a>
    <div id="resume-dialog" class="small-dialog zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide apply-popup">
        <div class="small-dialog-headline">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e('Send Message','workscout'); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="small-dialog-content">
            <!--<?php do_action( 'resume_manager_contact_details' ); ?>--> // Need to show phone content here !
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ahy help here how to show?

Comment: Try to check all meta of that particular page for that use $myvals = get_post_meta($post_id);

Comment: Can you send me some example how to do that?

Comment: I have added the example $myvals = get_post_meta($post->ID); it will return array so print that array using print_r function

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Myself :)

Issue was in this part:

```
add_filter( 'resume_manager_resume_fields', 'wpjms_admin_resume_form_fields' 
);
function wpjms_admin_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['_candidate_color'] = array(  // Here i didnt renamed field to _phone  lol :D
'label'         => __( 'Phone', 'job_manager' ),
'type'          => 'text',
'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter your phone', 'job_manager' ),
'description'   => '',
'priority' => 1
);

return $fields;

}
```

Now is working fine. Thanks anyone for your help.